# В чем смысл данной формы цикла while и данного кода в общем

Tags: java

```
import java.io.*;

public class FileCopy {

    public static void copy(String inFile, String outFile) {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024]; // Буфер байтів
        try (InputStream input = new FileInputStream(inFile);
             OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(outFile)) {
            int bytesRead;
            while ((bytesRead = input.read(buffer)) >= 0) {
                output.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            }
        } 
        catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }    
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        copy("bin/ua/in/iwanoff/java/first/FileCopy.class", "FileCopy.copy");
    }

}
```

Comment: Если это ваш код, то вы должны знать что его смысл.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Смыл в том, чтобы считывать содержимое потока порциями по 1024 байта в промежуточный буфер, и записывать его в выходной поток, пока все содержимое входного потока не будет считано (условие >= 0).